# How to submit a POST method form with PHP DOMdocument

Tags: php

I am working on a web crawler, and I want to submit a form with a legal email and password but without user interaction with the form and submit that form, and when the submission is successful I want to retrieve the the data of the profile.

For instance, take an example, for example I have a form on my server, which do POST request to server to submit the login data and then when the form is submitted, it is redirected to the profile page. So, when the redirection is done, I want to retrieve the profile data with my web crawler.

My web crawler works on PHP `DOMdocument()` class and I am able to get the class names and ids of the form input fields, which are the email and password fields. But now I do not know how to send my login data from here to that form I am playing with, and submit it through PHP.

This is what I have done so far :

```
$start = "http://bitbayofficial.com/";

function followLinks($l){

$doc = new DOMdocument();
$name = "Rupert COllingwood";
$email = "antesoft17@outlook.com";
$mess = " Hey I am a message dude !";
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($l));

$list =  $doc->getElementsByTagName("input");

foreach($list as $item){
    echo $item->getAttribute("class")."<br>";
}

}


followLinks($start);
```

This is my site, where it contains a simple form. I want to fill that with the information i have for now, with POST method. This form submit data with Ajax (POST method).

Comment: `DOMDocument` is just for parsing and manipulating an HTML document; it does not include any capabilities to do any HTTP requests. You'll need to do those through curl or whatever other HTTP client you prefer.

Comment: So its only possible with curl ? @deceze

Comment: *… or whatever other HTTP client you prefer.*